# Port forwarding / tunnelling for web server

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, port-forwarding

I've been looking for a tunneling service, but it seems like most information is outdated. I've been using [portmap.io](https://portmap.io/) for a while, but they only provide tunneling for one port.

The main requirements are a stable url, and it being free. Is there any suggestions on what people have been using?

[Pagekite](https://pagekite.net/) seems like a good alternative. I've obviously looked into ngrok, but they only provide dynamic urls in the free tier. [Localtunnel](https://localtunnel.github.io/www/) seem to be unreliable at best from reading around. I've also seen [SocketXP](https://www.socketxp.com/), but just wanted to see if there is anything considered to be the go-to.

Comment: shopping questione are off topic here

Comment: Fair point, I expected it tbh, however, any other place where it'd be on topic? @jsotola

Answer (score 0):

You can use an SSH reverse tunnel to expose the port on a remote server. I wrote a tutorial about the process if your interested in reading it...

https://link.medium.com/htYAwh8Kldb

Answer (score 0):

If you have your own external server, you can also try https://www.zerotier.com/. It connects all your servers/computers/laptops/etc in one network and then you can use internal ZeroTier's IPs to i.e., proxy_pass in Nginx.